# Mortgage calculator not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code, and it won't give the correct answer:

```
print("Hello and welcome to Up-to-the Mark Mortgage Calculator!")
lamt = input("\n\n please enter the loan amount.")
intRate = input("please enter the interest rate.")
numOy = input("please enter the number of years.")

L = lamt
i = intRate
n = numOy

mortgageAmt = int(int(L)* (int(i) * (1+int(i)) * (int(n))/12) / ((1 +int(i))*(int(n)/12)-1))
print(int(mortgageAmt))
input("prompt:")
```

Comment: So what answer *does* it give? For what inputs? And what were you expecting instead? Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you obsessing over `int`?

If you prompt a user to type in a number, and they don't, it will crash your program unless you use a `try: except:` block. Which is probably why it's not doing it correctly. `int` does not account for decimals, and if you want decimal numbers, use `float`. The general idea would be to wrap your questions into a `try` block with an `except ValueError:` so that way, if they do not type in a number, it will quit the program, instead of giving you a stack trace. I do not know what formula you were trying to do, nor if it was monthly payments or yearly. So I used a monthly mortgage payment formula.

```
try:
    lamt = float(input("\n\n please enter the loan amount: "))
    intRate = float(input("please enter the interest rate:")) #as decimal, not percentage.
    numOy = int(input("please enter the number of years: "))

    L = lamt
    i = intRate
    n = numOy

    mortgageAmt = (i*L)/((1 + i)**n - 1) #formula for monthly mortgage payments
    print(mortgageAmt)

except ValueError:
    print ("please use a proper numbers.")
```

Comment: yes it worked! thank you so much!!